# Confused by Laravel Blade templating @extends keyword

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am building a simple app with Laravel for the first time. I have been watching and reading videos on blade inheritance for hours and I do not see what I am doing wrong. The code currently looks like this:

The Route.php file:

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
   return View::make('home');
});
```

the `home.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('layouts.base')

@section('body')
    @include('body.main')
@stop

//other stuff
```

which is extending a layout file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    //head stuff
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="wrapper">
            @yield('body')
        </div><!-- end wrapper -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Now my problem is that I have a body file (below) which I want to have another yield section.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content col-md-12">
        @yield('card')
    </div>
</div>
```

and card.blade.php looks like this:

```
@extends('main')

@section('card')
    <div class="card">
        <h2>Hello</h2>
    </div>
@stop
```

This is just the most recent version. I have tried using different layout files, putting `extends` and `yield` in all different places in the main and layout pages. But nothing works. Right now my main content is displaying but not the card file (which I want to eventually repeat with different data pulled from eloquent).

I have read four or five different blade tutorials but nothing seems to work even when it appears to me like it definitely should. Most don't cover extending and yielding past one layer either which I have no problem with. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not use @include instead of yielding the section?

Comment: @Miks when I use include I get a `not found` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works this way, that when you call `View::make`, It goes from there 'up' using `@extends`.

1. home
2. layouts.base

And when going 'up' the ladder `@yield` includes the sections. So you would technically have to call `View::make('card')` which probably makes no sense.
Instead you may wanna try `@include`-ing the card template.

**card.blade.php**

```
<!-- no section or extends needed -->
<div class="card">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

**body.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="content col-md-12">
        @include('card')
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't work either. I get a `view [card] not found error. This is why I started down the road I did using `extend`. I have two `card` files, one in a sub directory and another in the same directory as `main`. neither one works. If I try and put another `card` blade in the main views directory I get a browser error `no data received`.

Comment: Including views doesn't work relative to the directory you're currently in. so you always have to specify the full "path". If card.blade.php is in views/body/ then you have to write `@include('body.card')`